# TypeScript: Why is for() loop over an enum's values different to Object.forEach() etc

Tags: typescript, enums

Why do the following two approaches to loop over an enum's keys in TypeScript (v4.2.4) yield different results?

```
enum Side {
  LEFT = 'LEFT',
  RIGHT = 'RIGHT',
}

// .map(), .reduce(), etc all work as I want and return the string key
Object.keys(Side).forEach(s => console.log(`forEach() ${s}`))
// Outputs:
// forEach() LEFT
// forEach() RIGHT

// but I originally used this approach and was surprised it returned the ordinal/index
for (const s in Object.keys(Side)) {
  console.log(`for() ${s}`)
}
// Outputs:
//   for() 0
//   for() 1
```

Thanks

Comment: You're doing two completely different things. `Object.keys()` returns an array. In the first example you call `.forEach()` on that array. `.forEach()` iterates over the elements and passes the element itself to the callback. In the second example you're using the array in a `for...in...` loop (which by itself is wrong, as `for...in...` is for objects and not arrays). `for...in...` iterates over the properties of an object - and not the values of the properties,

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, I've been coding in Python for the last couple of weeks and didn't spot I'd written 'in' where I meant 'of'!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Andreas in the comment, I was using the wrong `for` loop!

Changing to a for-of loop (as opposed to for-in) got what I wanted:

```
for (const s of Object.keys(Side)) {
  console.log(`for...of() ${s}`)
}
// Outputs:
// for...of() LEFT
// for...of() RIGHT
```